# Using, and parsing Doubles in request.getParameter("price");

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have to use doubles/int to parse some data that is numeric in nature, but I want to test for null.

I am collecting the data using a request.getParameter() call for my servlet.

This is my code:

I currently have a ClassCast exception saying that a String cannot be cast to an Int/Double.

How do I get around this error?

```
int quantity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity") == null ? "" : Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity")));
```

Comment: My bad no.. So if it is null you need it to return soemthing like.. `? "0"`

Comment: @3kings, now I have another error called operator == is undefined for types int, null.

Comment: @3kings, yes, I am using the ternary operator, but I have to do something special to my code before I am able to parse a String parameter into an int, or double. I just don't know how to fix this, and searching hasn't helped me.

Comment: `int quantity = request.getParameter("quantity") == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));`

Comment: That should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide the business logic for dealing with possible `null` values in the `quantity` parameter.  One sensible solution might be to assume that a missing or `null` value for `quantity` indicates that the quantity be zero:

```
String quantityStr = request.getParameter("quantity");
int quantity = 0;  // replace with whatever default value you want

// only parse for non-null, non-empty inputs
if (quantityStr != null && quantityStr.length() > 0) {
    quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityStr);
}
```

Comment: Yup. This did the trick. I added a 0, and the problem disappeared. I guess you can have an inventory of 0 (zero) items.